# Windows/C++: How do I determine the share name associated with a shared drive?

Tags: c++, windows, networking, share

Let's say I have a drive such as **C:\**, and I want to find out if it's shared and what it's share name (e.g. **C$**) is.

To find out if it's shared, I can use [NetShareCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Lmshare/nf-lmshare-netsharecheck).

How do I then map the drive to its share name? I thought that [NetShareGetInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Lmshare/nf-lmshare-netsharegetinfo) would do it, but it looks like that takes the share name, not the local drive name, as an input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all else fails, you could always use [NetShareEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netshareenum) and call [NetShareGetInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netsharegetinfo) on each.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [WNetGetConnectionA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetgetconnectiona) or [WNetGetConnectionW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetgetconnectionw).

Answer (score 0):

Use;

```
SHGetFileInfo with SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES
```

upon return check the dwAttributes flag for SFGAO_SHARE.

I'm not sure how to find the actual path tho.