# Translate Low level disk name to high level disk name

Tags: c#, performancecounter, hard-drive

I'm writing a basic diagnostic tool to show high level users where the bottlenecks are in their computers (so they understand that getting more ram/faster processor won't fix their problems).  I've been relying fairly heavily on the Performance Counter class within the .NET environment and so far and it's been working well.

When working with Logical Disk Drives however I've come across a slight issue.  On my computer I have a network drive for the office's shared documents drive (Z), however the performance counter refers to this drive as "HarddiskVolume2".  I know that under the hood this is what the logical drive is actually named, and the alias to "Z:" is really just for the user's benefit, but the users won't know what "HarddiskVolume2" is if I leave it.

Is there any way to translate "HarddiskVolume2" to "Z" using any system calls?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594/windows-c-how-do-i-determine-the-share-name-associated-with-a-shared-drive

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/QueryDosDevice.html

Comment: @Jay, I don't think it's a duplicate.  That question is about C++ and mine is C#.  Would you call it a duplicate if you found an answer to my question in python for example?

Comment: @HansPassant The documentation is a little light on what those functions actually *do* but it looks promising.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Jrud: the C# language does not have a feature to do what you want. The feature is in the _platform_ API, which is at best language-agnostic (and in reality, is closely tied to C/C++). Now, that said...the suggested "duplicate" is specifically about network shares, while the title of your question _seems_ to suggest you may be interested in a more general answer than just dealing with network shares (it's not really clear from your question, since the example you use _is_ about network shares). If and when you improve the question, do keep in mind that existing information may not be in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see a list of all your mapped drives and their resolved paths:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    GetUNCDrives().Select(kvp => 
        string.Format("{0} => {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value))));
```

If you want to get a list of possible shorter resolutions for a path:

```
var longPath = @"\\HarddiskVolume2\ent\RRPSTO\foobar\file.txt";

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GetShortPaths(longPath)));
```

If you just assume there is only going to be one mapped drive resolution, you could, just select the first one:

```
var shortPaths = GetShortPaths(longPath);
var path = shortPaths.Length > 0 ? shortPaths[0] : longPath;
```

Or you could pick from the list based on how deep the network map was. So to get the shortest mapping path (not shortest path name) you just count how many '/' are in the path.

Or you could cheat and just take the one with the shortest path name. This isn't guaranteed to be the most simple path though.

However you want to do it, the code below is what makes the code above work.
You'll need these guys:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.IO;
```

And you'll also need to include the `System.Management.dll` included in your project references.

**Code:**

```
/// <summary>Gets array of all possible shorter paths for provided path.</summary>
/// <param name="path">The path to find alternate addresses for.</param>
static string[] GetShortPaths(string path)
{
    return GetUNCDrives()
        .Where(kvp => path.StartsWith(kvp.Value))
        .Select(kvp => Path.Combine(kvp.Key, path.Substring(kvp.Value.Length + 1)))
        .ToArray();
}

/// <summary>Gets all mapped drives and resolved paths.</summary>
/// <returns>Dictionary: Key = drive, Value = resolved path</returns>
static Dictionary<string, string> GetUNCDrives()
{
    return DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        .Where(di => di.DriveType == DriveType.Network)
        .ToDictionary(di => di.RootDirectory.FullName
                    , di => GetUNCPath(di.RootDirectory.FullName.Substring(0, 2)));
}

/// <summary>Attempts to resolve the path/root to mapped value.</summary>
/// <param name="path">The path to resolve.</param>
static string GetUNCPath(string path)
{
    if (path.StartsWith(@"\\"))
        return path;

    var mo = new ManagementObject(string.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", path));

    return Convert.ToUInt32(mo["DriveType"]) == (UInt32)DriveType.Network 
            ? Convert.ToString(mo["ProviderName"]) 
            : path;
}
```